# Script loses colour coding after very long string + string issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, varchar

So, I have the following script:

```
declare @v varchar(max) = '', @x int = 0
WHILE @x<=100000
BEGIN
    set @x += 1

    set @v += cast(@x as varchar(9))
END

select len(@v), @x, @v,
    len('{Insert @v result}')

select 1
```

Please replace {Insert @v result} with @v's result. Could not copy-paste because of character length.

My intention was to get an idea as to how long a list of IDs could get.

I have the following issues:

- Query Editor loses colour coding from the line where you copy paste @v. This includes keywords, strings, comments, etc. is this normal?
- When copy-pasting the result for @v I only get up to 10957, is this a flaw in my script or a clipboard limitation?

Comment: This is a known bug that has to do with displaying strings longer than 43679 characters. One work-around is to convert it to XML. I'm not sure if there are other workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. On my installation of SQL though it happens when exceeding 32757 characters.